# Should've seen the [sign]s coming

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, retag-request, synonym-request

I'd like to propose the tag [sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sign) for burnination. The word sign can be used for multiple purposes. Currently the description directly points to [digital-signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/digital-signature) but there are also questions related to the sign of a literal value (for instance -1).

I've just proposed for [signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signing) as a synonym for [digital-signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/digital-signature) as that makes sense (the equivalent for changing sign is called sign-change) and most questions with that tag do seem to mean [digital-signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/digital-signature). However, I do not see this as a good option for [sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sign).

If possible the tag should be replaced with [digital-signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/digital-signature) for most questions. For now I just found out that I missed a whole lot of questions because they used this tag.

Comment: We''l take this thread as a [sign] for burnination

Comment: I see [sign]s of burnination in the sky.

Comment: Burnination? [sign] me up!

Comment: Also someone please remove the tag info. It is pure plagiarism from wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature

Comment: This is not a good [sign].

Comment: 35 upvotes, but it hasn't been burninated. What gives? Anything else that I should do?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes There's a [long list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=&q=%5Bburninate-request%5D+-%5Bstatus-*%5D&sort=votes) of burnination requests. We'll get to it... eventually. If you're interested in the burnination progress, the community have a [chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165597) to co-ordinate the effort.